# Saving canvas image onto host server

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, save

I have a created a sketchpad canvas and I wanted to see if it's possible now to have the save function save the canvas to the server so when the site is reloaded the last saved canvas appears ready to continue drawing on.

This will essentially allow people to collaborate on drawing on the canvas.

I have a save function now which just renders the canvas as png next to the original canvas but I'm unsure how to take it to the next stage.

On a separate note - it would be good if the save button could be removed and the save function could be called every few seconds - but that possibly would be tricky.

```html
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }

    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;

    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="can" width="500px" height="675px" style="position:absolute;border:2px solid;background:url(http://files.cargocollective.com/715286/sticker.jpg);background-size:100%100%;"></canvas>
        <div style="position:relative;top:40px;left:600px;">Eraser</div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:100px;left:600px;width:15px;height:15px;background:black;border:2px solid;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;">Pen</div>
        <img id="canvasimg" style="position:relative;top:10%;left:600px;" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:relative;top:150px;left:594px;">
        <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:relative;top:180px;left:550px;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: are you open to storing the image on the client? how about on the server - have you thought about if/how you'd want to store the image there?

Comment: i was thinking i could have the image saved on my server, then have the script call to save every 3 seconds over-righting the file

Comment: ok, great! What server-side framework are you running? .NET? PHP?

Comment: PHP isnt supported on the framework im using unfortunately, which makes it a lot harder

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your script/html that wraps the img into a form tag and uses `setInterval` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp to invoke the save function every 3 seconds (uncomment out the line in `init` to enable).

How you save the image once it is on the server is, perhaps, a separate question that would depend heavily on your circumstances. Regardless of how it is saved, the image data will be transferred up to the server via the form POST, where you can do whatever you wish with the data.

```html
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;

    var saveTimer;
    function onSaveTimer() {
          save();              
    }


    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
        
       // saveTimer = setInterval(onSaveTimer, 3000);
    }

    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;

    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function save() {
        
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        if (dataURL) { 
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
            return true; // will POST form to the server
        }
        return false; // will not POST to server

    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }

        }
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="can" width="500px" height="675px" style="position:absolute;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
        <div style="position:relative;top:40px;left:600px;">Eraser</div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:100px;left:600px;width:15px;height:15px;background:black;border:2px solid;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;">Pen</div>
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="save">
        <img id="canvasimg" style="position:relative;top:10%;left:600px;" style="display:none;">
</form>
        <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:relative;top:150px;left:594px;">
        <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:relative;top:180px;left:550px;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to save the info as a DataURI, and then call that cookie into an image element's src. Then, use canvas to pull the image from the img element.

EDIT:
If you want to save it to the host server, use PHP and the following:

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/myFileName.png",base64_decode(str_replace(" ","+",$_GET["data"])));
```

And to save, just send a request to the php page with variable "data" set to canvas.toDataURL()

EDIT 2:
Here's an example of the non-php solution:
http://id0t.x10.mx/StackOverflow/demo1.html

Comment: Sam thank you so much thats a brilliant idea! PHP isnt supported on the framework I'm using so good alternative. Have you any ideas what this would look like? Im new to URIs

Comment: If you must use a hosted image, use something like Imgur's API. https://apidocs.imgur.com/

Comment: The issue with the cookie route is that it would only be saved for that one user. Is there a way of storing the cookie onto a server so that if visited by another ip they will see the cookie the last user stored?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't...unless you use an external database that's accessed by a script tag containing the url and the data in a query string. If somehow javascript can write to a file, then yes, you can just write to the file. You can already read files with javascript, but writing to them...

Comment: If you can use node.js, then you should be ok...do you use GitHub? Own server? Something else?

Comment: Im using a hosting platform called Cargo. And with that I only have access to CSS and JS. I was thinking i need to find a way to save the canvas data every x seconds to the server. Then keep re-fetching the canvas data from the server every x seconds to show users. So if you know of any scripts that can save a canvas to a server that would be great